# What causing this space between tables?

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-spacing

What is causing the vertical space between these two tables?

[image]

I am inputting the following .tex file into my main file

Let the following be A.tex

```
{\fontfamily{lmr}
 \fontsize{25pt}{20pt}
 \selectfont\begin{center}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.5pt}   
\begin{table}[t]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            X &\multirow{2}{*}{X}\\
            X &\\
            \hline
            X &\multirow{2}{*}{--}\\
            X &\\
            \hline
            X &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\underline{0 \hspace{0.01cm} X \hspace{0.16cm}}}\\
            
            X &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{
            \underline{1 \hspace{0.01cm} X \hspace{1.00cm}} \hspace{0.50cm}  
            \underline{2 \hspace{0.01cm} X\hspace{0.50cm}}}\\
            
            X  & \\
            X  & \\
            \hline
            
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table} 

\begin{table}[t]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|ll|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{X’s Profile}}\\
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Name \hspace{1cm} X}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Date of Birth \hspace{1cm} X, X \hspace{0.9cm}}\\
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}&\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Nationality \hspace{1cm} X}}&\multirow{2}{*}{}\\
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}&\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Curriculum Vitae}}\\
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Educational Background}}\\
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}\\
            \hline
            From&\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\makecell[l]{X \\ 
                      X, X\\
                      \textit{X}\\}}}\\
            
            \hspace{1cm} X &&\\
            To&&\\
            \hspace{1cm} X &&\\
            \hline
            
            
            From&\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\makecell[l]{X \\
                      \textit{X}}}}\\
            \hspace{1cm} X &&\\
            To&&\\
            \hspace{1cm} X &&\\
            \hline
            
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table} 

\end{center}}
```

Here's my some preamble of main.tex and how I input A.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont \itshape Master's Thesis}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont \itshape \nouppercase \rightmark}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\fontsize{10}{12} \thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style = ieee, sort = none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{enumitem} %control width of itemized text
\usepackage{amsmath} % Matrix equation
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % for equation numbering
\usepackage{amssymb} %for check mark symbol
\usepackage[cleardoublepage=empty]{scrextend}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

.
.
.
\begin{document}
.
.
\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{A}

.
.
\end{document}
```

I admit I got the template from someone else, so maybe one of those preambles is causing this? any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what is the intention of `\fontsize{25pt}{20pt}` ? there is no way to have even linespacing with that. It specifies the impossible fitting of 25pt font on baselines 20pt apart. TeX will try to do this and produce inconsistent baseline spacing depending on the size of the letters used in each line.

Comment: `\begin{center}` adds vertical space, use `\centering` in floats to avoid that.

Comment: If a  table ( =`tabular`) must be in top of a  fixed page without a  caption, just do not use a float  (=`table`). If both tables (tabulars) could move to the top of another page, just place both tables (`tabular`s) in a single float (`table`). Note that two tables without a `table`(err... I mean the float) move just  like two big characters, i.e., they cannot change of position respect the main  text, but vertical skips betwwen still could change  depending on remaining contents to avoid ragged end of pages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as I said, I got this code from someone, not entirely sure what that intention is, thanks for pointing this and the `\centering` as well, I solved my problem with Fran's solution.
@Fran your suggestions directed me to put both `tabulars` inside one `table`, and then it works as I expected after putting `[h!]` argument on it, thankss!